Cloudpage smartcapture won't submit when pre populated
I am trying to create a survey using smartcapture in cloudpage. As the survey will be sent to existing customer, I'd like it to be pre populated with the information we already have (i.e. name, email address etc.)
I added a HTML block above the form with script below.
%%[
    SET @SubKey = AttributeValue("Subscriber Key")
    SET @FirstName = Lookup('Brian test', "First Name", "Subscriber Key", @SubKey)
    SET @LastName = Lookup('Brian test', "Last Name", "Subscriber Key", @SubKey)
    SET @EmailAddress = Lookup('Brian test', "Email Address", "Subscriber Key", @SubKey)
]%%

And in each field, I added the below.
value="%%=v(@XXX)=%%" 

I published it and the form was correctly pre populated, whereas the submit button wouldn't work at all. The submit worked properly when it's not prefilled though. Could anyone advise please?
Thank you!

What do you mean when you say that the submit button didn't work? Any errors occur?

@DucLe when i clicked submit, nothing happened. It didn't show the message nor redirected me to the other page as I set up. And the data wasn't recorded as well.

Can you add the part how you redirect from the smart capture cloudpage to the page you set up here?

I know this is not an answer to your technical question, but:
suggestion : dont do it.
a) you are exposing Personally Identifiable Data behind a link.
You cannot prevent forwarding of the email -> you cannot prevent PII data going into wrong hands. Just dont prefill data from your system on forms you send out via email, just use them to collect.
b) if you have the data already, why display it to the exact person you just sent to?
If the customer changes nothing, you could just omit it and your form gets shorter.
If the customer DOES change e.g. their email, what are you expecting to do? Update the email? Do you have an email change process in place? Will you update it on All Subscribers etc? Are other processes affected by a sudden email change?
What I am trying to say: there is very little benefit of this presumably little thing that I could imagine, compared to the potential issues with security, data integrity and scope creep / rabbit holes.
